# Format plugin for CKEditor not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, ckeditor

I installed CKEditor plugin on my Wordpress site, and I want to assign paragraph format "Normal (div)" a class.

I tried to install [FORMAT](http://ckeditor.com/addon/format) plugin (plus all dependencies) by adding plugins to plugin folder and added:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'panel,button,listblock,floatpanel,richcombo,format';
```

into CKEDITOR.config.html [I followed the instructions](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins-section-manual-installation)

(I tried saving the plugin files both into `WP/wp-content/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/plugins and WP/wp-content/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/ckeditor/plugins`)

Than I edited the plugin.js (FORMAT plugin), but nothing happened:

```
/**
 * The style definition to be used to apply the `'Normal (DIV)'` format. 
 *      config.format_div = { element : 'div', attributes : { 'class' : 'myClass' } };
 * @cfg {Object} [format_div={ element: 'div' }]
 * @member CKEDITOR.config
 */

CKEDITOR.config.format_div = { element : 'div', attributes : { 'class' : 'myClass' } };`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Could I assign a class for div without a plugin, maybe by adding something to the `CKEDITOR.config.format_div={element:"div"}` line in ckeditor.sj file?

Comment: Can you add `config.format_div` inside config.js and not plugin.js. Why did you put it in plugin.js in in the first place? Isn't it nicer to have all configuration inside config.js?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the order matters?  The following worked for me:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'panel,floatpanel,listblock,button,richcombo,format';
```

Also, I found CKBuilder to be somewhat unhelpful in the sense that it did not download all of my plugin directories.  So I had to manually install all of the above plugins.